# Drop rows if a list of values appear in both columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
from to value 
A    B   2
Z    B   5
C    A   7
A    C   7
D    E   7
G    H   5
H    E   4
F    C   2
A    P   4
..
```

and a list of ids

```
lst = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F']
```

I want to drop rows for which both `from` and `to` contain an element from the list.

Thus, the desired df:

```
from to value 
A    B   2
Z    B   5
D    E   7
G    H   5
H    E   4
A    P   4
..
```

Comment: the logic is unclear, do you mean within a value group? why did the `F    C   2` row disappear?

Comment: bc both F and C are in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like sql:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A','B',2],
    ['Z','B',5],
    ['C','A',7],
    ['A','C',7],
    ['D','E',7],
    ['G','H',5],
    ['H','E',4],
    ['G','C',2],
    ['A','P',4]
], columns=['From', 'To', 'value'])

lst = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F']

df.query('not (From in @lst and To in @lst)')

    From    To  value
0   A   B   2
1   Z   B   5
4   D   E   7
5   G   H   5
6   H   E   4
7   G   C   2
8   A   P   4
```

(note capitalization of 'From' and 'To' to avoid keyword conflict)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) combined with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
lst = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F']

out = df[~df[['from', 'to']].isin(lst).all(axis=1)]
```

Or combine two masks:

```
out = df[~(df['from'].isin(lst) & df['to'].isin(lst))]
```

output:

```
  from to  value
0    A  B      2
1    Z  B      5
4    D  E      7
5    G  H      5
6    H  E      4
8    A  P      4
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to test it?